# How do I reach the car park platform (Pennsylvania Plaza)?

Tags: the-division

A toolbox I have to open is located on the upper platform (see purple icon on map, the game did show the exact location). I can't climb on top of cars or approach from the sides and I don't know if I can reach the apartment's roof on behind.

[image]

Location on the map:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the toolbox is on the second level? Have you opened the toolbox in the lower right corner of the screenshot?

Comment: @Adeese: Yes I have. The game highlighted the toolbox on the second level.

Comment: @user598527 Please accept RD15's answer. It is correct and there's nothing on the cars, you can't climb them. Reference: 200+ hours in the game.

Answer (score 3):

I believe all of the tool boxes can be found between the cars.  I have not seen one on the second level in areas like this.

Comment: I no longer have access to the game (the free weekend ended). As this is  an early area in the game, you could create a new character and test.